# where to put the MySQL connection code from MCPKit in cocoa

Tags: mysql, cocoa, class, frameworks, database-connection

I am trying to plan out where to put my MySQL connection code -

`MCPConnection *conn = [[MCPConnection alloc] initToHost:@"" withLogin:@"" usingPort:@""];`

etc. from MCPKit on the mac. My aim is to make as few connection instances as possible through the whole app (if possible just one will be awesome).

The only 3 places i can think of putting it are -

- The app delegate, but then how would I use the same connection in other classes (data encapsulation)
- Place code in Each and every Window/View controller that requires it to fulfil each individual purpose (but this means a lot more code and a large number of connections which i do no want).
- Or finally setting up an individual class for all the the MySQL queries and a singular connection. (but then how to do that so that the methods in this class are easily callable, or so that the SQL statements/queries can be adaptive enough for every other class that uses the methods).

i hope that hasn't been too confusing - the main point is this - where do i put the connection code, does it carry between classes well, or does it need to be called individually and successively throughout use of the app.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, you can use Singleton pattern and replace init code with call to static getInstance. The only public method of singleton wrapper would be getConnection, which then you use as normal. Yep, you can pull common sql-building methods into that class, but that leads to code bloat, better use Flyweight pattern for separate-type queries.

The only drawback of such design is that access to that single shared database connection must always be serialized, which may render some your UI slow and irresponsive if there are multiple simultaneous threads accessing database.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but i couldn't understand a lot of that, might you be able to put it in simpler terms for me?